# How to call SamsungMobilePrint scan function via intent

Tags: android

For some reason I would like to call SamsungMobilePrint/Scan directly from an app with startActivity.

Samsung suggested

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.print.mobileprint.action.SCAN");
startActivity(intent);
```

but this leads to a Nullpointer-Exception somewhere within Java.

I am able to call the Print-Fuction directly without problems by doing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.print.mobileprint.action.PRINT");
Uri uri= Uri.parse(printfileName);    //Test_document.pdf speech.txt
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONTENT", uri );
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONTENT_TYPE", "DOCUMENT");
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.AUTO_RETURN", "TRUE");
startActivity(intent);
```

I can also call the whole MobilePrint app by:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.print.mobileprint");
startActivity(intent);
```

Has anybody been able to call the SamsungMobilePrint/Scan using

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.print.mobileprint.action.SCAN"); ?
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I finally found a solution. There was an "Extra" missing. Samsung documentation was a little misleading.
It finally works like this:`

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent("com.sec.print.mobileprint.action.SCAN");
if (launchIntent != null) {     //null pointer check in case package name was not found
    launchIntent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONNECTION_TYPE", "WIFI");
    launchIntent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.AUTO_RETURN", "TRUE");
}
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

e.g. a "CONNECTION_TYPE"-Extra is mandatory in this case.